# Is there a legal way to obtain Windows 7 DVD?

Tags: windows-7, dvd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

Bought a new laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium and want to format and reinstall.  Is there a legal way to obtain a copy of Windows 7 on DVD?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can download and burn a copy of Windows 7.  The links can be found here:

http://techpp.com/2009/11/11/download-windows-7-iso-official-direct-download-links/

However, you have to have a valid license key to validate your install.  The OEM license key found on the sticker that came with your machine will work provided you install the same version of Windows.

Comment: +1 for you! I didn't realise the ISOs were available online as DDL with Microsoft's blessing. Although I am not sure if using the retail media is the same as using the OEM media, I have been caught up previously when using an OEM key with retail media.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a legal way to obtain a copy of Windows 7 on DVD?

When you purchase a copy of Windows (it comes with your laptop, you get an OEM license), you purchase a license to use Windows, not a license to have a copy of the DVD. You can get an image of the DVD from anywhere, it is legal to use Bittorrent for this as long as you are downloading a 1:1 copy of the OEM media and you have the license key for Windows it will work.

Note that if you can't find your OEM media online, you can contact them and they will usually send you a DVD for a fee.

Bear in mind that most laptops come with a recovery DVD or software hidden on a hard drive partition that will allow you to restore your computer to the original state.

Answer (score 0):

Did the laptop come with a  recovery disk? If so, you're set.

Otherwise, the only route I know of is to go to Office Max and buy a copy (or you favorite brick/click store).

Comment: Or you could just burn a disc. It's not like having a burnt copy of the media is illegal.

Comment: I can make a recovery disk but the point is I just want to install windows, and not all the other crap that comes on a new computer.