# Windows 7 Trial Version

Tags: windows-7

Looking for URL to download a trial version of Windows 7 to run on another partition. I want to have a 'play' on W7 and get to know it (and its possible problems) before I go out and buy a new machine with W7 already installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "trial" version of Windows 7 in the sense that it's a different version, since they all come with a 30 day grace period before you must enter a product key. Take advantage of this, burn an ISO of retail media.

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/141117/is-there-a-legal-way-to-obtain-windows-7-dvd) for ISOs.

Comment: You can try it for 120 days, and 360 days with a simple reg trick. Or for unlimited time with a simple task scheduler job but this is illegal already. (The 360 days is not as far as I know. The 120 is totally legal.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Windows 7 Enterprise trial though technically its intended for business IT use. You'll need a Live account.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to download a 90 day evaluation of Windows 7 Enterprise.

You need a Live ID/Microsoft account to download.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-7-enterprise

UPDATE: Since the release of Windows 10 Technical Preview, Windows 7 is no longer available on this link for download.