# Upgrade from Windows 7 32-bit with Downloadable Windows 7 64-bit ISO?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)
>   [Where I can I legally download Windows 7 installation .ISO files?](https://superuser.com/questions/280557/where-i-can-i-legally-download-windows-7-installation-iso-files)

I want to upgrade my Windows 7 32-bit to Windows 7 64-bit because I'm fed-up with the memory limitations.  I have a valid Windows 7 key, which based on a search of SO, should be valid for 64-bit.  The issue I have, is I don't have a 64-bit ISO.  I know Microsoft used to have TechNet downloads of all the OS ISOs, but I can't find them.

I understand that some might scream 'piracy', but I have a completely valid, purchased key and I assume asking for the ISO is completely legal and doesn't contravene any SU rules.  Can anyone direct me on how to get a 64-bit ISO?

Help is appreciated.

-- I was told that the 32-bit ISO allowed 64-bit installation, this isn't the case with the ISO I have at least.  But if this can be done, tips on how to do it would be great :)

Comment: OK, looks that with some determined googling I found some links.  Can anyone confirm the byte-size of the ISO, just in case I'm downloading a phoney?

Comment: Happy for this to be closed - looks like that (and then this: http://superuser.com/questions/141117/is-there-a-legal-way-to-obtain-windows-7-dvd) was what I was looking for.  The DDLs I'm already downloading from were Digital River ones - so that confirms their legitimacy. +1 for the help :)